# Spring Web Services within JBoss - Two dynamic wsdl's with different locationUri, but both can be accessed in both locations

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jboss, wsdl

I have a Spring web services project. I have split the services into two different wsdl's.

```
<ws:dynamic-wsdl id="myDefinitionOne"
    portTypeName="Test" locationUri="http://server/basedirectory/subdirectoryone">
    <ws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/my-schema-one.xsd" />
</ws:dynamic-wsdl>

<ws:dynamic-wsdl id="myDefinitionTwo"
    portTypeName="Test" locationUri="http://server/basedirectory/subdirectorytwo">
    <ws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemas/my-schema-two.xsd" />
</ws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

This is running on JBoss AS 7.1.1. What I dont understand is, I would have thought that only the myDefinitionOne wsdl could be accessed in 'http://myserver/basedirectory/**subdirectoryone**/' and the same, only myDefinitionTwo wsdl could be accessed in 'http://myserver/basedirectory/**subdirectorytwo**/'

But as it goes, both wsdl's can be accessed from either URL.

I am running SoapUI and I can run end point tests for both sets of services from eiter URL.

Is there something I have missed here, as my aim was to separate out the authentication on the URL's, i.e. /http://myserver/basedirectory/subdirectorytwo/ and /http://myserver/basedirectory/subdirectorytwo/ on each service, but I can't do this, if they can both be accessed from both locations.

I am also running this through IIS.

Can anyone help with my undertanding on this.

---

Based on the comment, this is what is in my web.xml file

This is what is in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ws-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/subdirectoryone/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservices-auth</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ws-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webservices-auth</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/subdirectorytwo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So does this not specify it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

`ws:dynamic-wsdl` is just a way to serve out the wsdl for your Spring-WS service given the schema for your types - the endpoint itself is not really associated with what you describe in your `ws:dynamic-wsdl`. That is the reason why no matter what locationUri you put it gets handled by Spring-WS `MessageDispatcherServlet` based on the `servlet-mapping` that you must have provided in the `web.xml` file.

Spring-WS finds the endpoint method based on the payload or the soapaction.

**Based on updates**
Your approach will not work, as essentially the two `MessageDispatcherServlet` are still pointing to the same configuration. So for eg, if a request comes to /subdirectory1/* it will be intercepted by the first MessageDispatcherServlet, it would at some point check the payload, internally it then checks a mapping from the payload to the endpoint to find the correct endpoint to dispatch the call to. The exact same thing will happen whether you send a request to /subdirectory1/* or /subdirectory2/*.

If you absolutely need to do this, how about creating two spring-ws configuration files - say ws-config1.xml and ws-config2.xml, remove `<component-scan/>` if you have it, and explicitly add the relevant endpoint beans explicitly to each of the config files. This can work.

Comment: Please see my new edit to include the web.xml file. I am not sure if this is correct?